# Xeric: checking for OpenSSL... configure: error: Cannot find ssl libraries

Tags: macos, irc

When trying to run ./config for Xaric, I get the following error:

checking for OpenSSL... configure: error: Cannot find ssl libraries

Has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Which OS / distribution are you using, are the openssl libraries installed?

Comment: Mac OS X El Capitan, BSD. Don't know if libraries are installed. Where to check?